# Which performance measure to report?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, bootstrap, random-forest, caret

I've trained a random forest regression model using boot632 resampling and the caret package. The output of the model tuning process gives a few different performance measures.

```
Random Forest 

201 samples
 14 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (100 reps) 

Summary of sample sizes: 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, 201, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  RMSE      Rsquared   RMSE SD    Rsquared SD  RMSEApparent  RsquaredApparent
   2    1.775407  0.2457171  0.1183597  0.05434687   1.5063403     0.5300746       
   3    1.716288  0.2976727  0.1255332  0.05412185   1.3085394     0.6729571       
 ...
  11    1.559582  0.3837259  0.1416958  0.05378046   0.7902441     0.9013706       
  12    1.556493  0.3857319  0.1433656  0.05361161   0.7782075     0.9062290       
  13    1.553249  0.3877148  0.1443430  0.05420465   0.7661420     0.9108585       

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the one SE rule.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 11.
```

When interpreting/reporting the results of the model would it be best to report `RMSE` and `R squared`, or the `RMSEApparent` and `RsquaredApparent`? I understand that the `Apparent` measures are a combination of the simple bootstrap estimate and the estimate from re-predicting the training set, which is leading me towards using the `RMSE` and `Rsquared` measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `RMSE` and `Rsquared`. The others are there as an oversight and I'll probably avoid printing them in the next version.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for you answer. Are the `RMSE` and `Rsquared` the boot632 adjusted metrics? i.e. (0.632 × simple bootstrap estimate) + (0.368 × apparent error rate)?